# Insert Data into Oracle. Java Jframe

Tags: java, mysql, date, insert, jframe

Been trying to insert data into oracle. I troubleshoot it and I manage to get `system.out.println` 1 and 2.

Here is my code. PS. I suspect maybe is the dates using jDatepicker.

```
   private void AddActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                    
    // TODO add your handling code here:


   SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
   String startDate = formatter.format(csd.getDate());
   String endDate = formatter.format(ced.getDate());
   String id = cid.getText();
   String name = cname.getText();
   int year = cyear.getYear();
   String ccountry = country.getText();
   String ccity = city.getText();
   String cvenue = venue.getText();
   String contactemail = email.getText();

  try{

  Connection dbConnection = getDBConnection();
      System.out.println(1);
   String insert = "insert into conference values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
   PreparedStatement ps = dbConnection.prepareStatement(insert);
   ps.setString(1, id);
   ps.setString(2, name);
   ps.setInt(3, year);
   ps.setString(4, startDate);
   ps.setString(5, endDate);
   ps.setString(6, ccountry);
   ps.setString(7, ccity);
   ps.setString(8, cvenue);
   ps.setString(9, contactemail);
   System.out.println(2);
   ps.executeUpdate();
   System.out.println("louis");
  }
  catch (Exception ex) {
  }

}
```

Comment: Whats the error that you are getting?

Comment: No error, but nothing happens when i add

Comment: I think the auto commit is set to false. can you put 

    dbConnection.commit() after the executeUpdate().

Comment: Are the dates stored with the `DATE` data type in the db? If they are, you don't need to convert them to strings; use `ps.setDate()` instead. Also, it's clearer if you explicitly define the column names in the `INSERT` statement. This way it's obvious which index position corresponds to which column.

Comment: it is much quicker to type "ex.printStackTrace();" than to post here and get all kinds of wild guesses...